# How to send base64 images though flask send_files

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import abort, send_file
from routes import app as upload

from libs.mysql_connector import Data

from io import BytesIO
import base64

@upload.route('/upload/student_pic/<int:id>')
def student_pic(id):
    try:
        data = Data(f"""SELECT * FROM `student_list` WHERE `Student_ID` = {id}""")
        base64_data = data[0]['Picture']
        image_binary  = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_data))
        return send_file(
            image_binary,
            mimetype='image/jpeg'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return abort(404)
```

I want to send base64 file img to display dynamically in the flask. Please help me
It sends `'Data' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: This looks wide open to SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Later I figure out how can I solve it.

```
from flask import abort, send_file
from routes import app as upload

from libs.mysql_connector import Data

import io
from PIL import Image
import base64

@upload.route('/upload/student_pic/<int:id>.png')
def student_pic(id):
    try:
        data = Data(f"""SELECT * FROM `student_list` WHERE `Student_ID` = {id}""")
        data = data.get()
        base64_data = data[0]['Picture']
        base64_data = base64_data.split(",")
        base64_data = base64_data[1]

        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(bytes(base64_data, "utf-8"))))

        byte_io = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(byte_io, 'PNG')
        byte_io.seek(0)

        return send_file(byte_io, mimetype='image/png')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return abort(404)
```